# How to use a jsf template with values

Tags: jsf, templates, jsf-2

i am using a template for my views, as i have 10 views and all need the same code apart from the values.

The values that are just outputing infomration like text etc i have done fine, however what i am wondering is how do i go about adding values that pull data from another section of the application into the template

currently i have :

```
                <p:spinner id="ajaxspinner0-19"value="#{markingBean.markToEdit.markSectionOne}" 
                           stepFactor = "1"  min="0" max="19" 
                           disabled = "#{formBean.number != 1}" >  
                    <p:ajax update="ajaxspinnervalue " process="@this" />  
                </p:spinner>
```

this code is not in the template at all jsut in the view and works well, the value would be displayed in the spinner as say 71

what i am wondering is how can i have this in the template where it will work on load up just like this but also give the chance so for page one i would have `value="#{markingBean.markToEdit.markSectionOne}"`  and for page two `value="# {markingBean.markToEdit.markSectionTwo}"` etc etc

the important thing here is that when the page loads up it acts exactly the same way as the top example and will display the correct value

Thanks Guys !

EDIT:

This is the view currently

```
    <ui:fragment > <!-- rendered="{request.isUserInRole('')}">  IMPLEMENT ONCE WE HAVE A LOG ON SYSTEM-->
        <p:growl id="growl" />  
        <p:progressBar widgetVar="pbAjax" ajax="true" value="7" labelTemplate="{value}%" styleClass="animated"/>  
        <h3>Project Marking - Section One</h3>
        <h4>Context, Aims and Objectives</h4>

        <f:event listener="#{tooltipBean.setupForPageA}" type="preRenderView" />    

        <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/templates/commonForm.xhtml"/>
    </ui:fragment>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put this `p:spinner` part in a `ui:composition` like so:

**spinner.xhtml**

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:u="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/ui" 
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

      <p:spinner id="#{spinnerId}"value="#{selectedValue}" 
                       stepFactor = "1"  min="0" max="19" 
                       disabled = "#{disabled}" >  
                <p:ajax update="#{update}" process="@this" />  
      </p:spinner>

</ui:composition>
```

**View**

Then you could include it in your view with `ui:param`

```
<ui:include src="path/to/your/spinner.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="selectedValue" value="#{markingBean.markToEdit.markSectionOne}" />
        <ui:param name="disabled" value="#{formBean.number != 1}" />
        <ui:param name="update" value="ajaxspinnervalue" />
        <ui:param name="spinnerId" value="ajaxspinner1" />
</ui:include>
<ui:include src="path/to/your/spinner.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="selectedValue" value="#{markingBean.markToEdit.markSectionTwo}" />
        <ui:param name="disabled" value="#{formBean.number != 1}" />
        <ui:param name="update" value="ajaxspinnervalue" />
        <ui:param name="spinnerId" value="ajaxspinner2" />
</ui:include>
```

I hope I understood you right.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, thanks to your suggestion i now have it working thanks a lot !